# I want to attach another activity which shows user informations after login through facebook social login.How to do this?

Tags: android

I want to create another activity and after clicking continue I want to go that activity and there I want to show first name and last name.Please help me.Thank u.

Comment: This question is too broad; please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices

- Use `SharedPreference` in `Application` class to store after login and call from another `Activity`
- User `Intent` to pass serialized/parceable object from login to call from another `Activity`